# How to coerce an expression to a class known only at runtime?

Tags: r

R has many means of coercion: `as.logical`, `as.integer`, `as.data.frame`, etc.

Using these functions, however, requires knowing in advance ("at compile time") the target class (`logical`, `integer`, `data.frame`, etc.).

But in the problem I'm working on, I need to coerce `expr1` to `class(expr2)`, where `expr1` and `expr2` are arbitrary R expressions whose classes are not known until runtime.

I don't expect that R has any built-in support for this exact use-case, but I hope that it does for the one of coercing an arbitrary expression to an arbitrary class.  IOW, I hope that R already has something like `coerce(expr, a.class)`<sup>1</sup>.

---

I know that I can roll my own `coerce`, like this:

```
coerce <- function (expr, a.class) {
  ## coerce expr to a.class
  switch(a.class,
         character = as.character(expr),
           logical = as.logical(expr),
           integer = as.integer(expr),
           numeric = as.numeric(expr),

           # yadda-yadda-yadda

                     stop(sprintf('unsupported class: %s', a.class)))
}

> coerce(5, "foo")
[1] "5"
```

Also, I know that one can also resort to this:

```
coerce2 <- function (expr, a.class) {
  ## coerce expr to a.class; take 2
  rcode <- sprintf("as.%s(expr)", a.class)
  tryCatch(eval(parse(text=rcode)),
           error = function (condtion) {
                     stop(sprintf('unsupported class: %s', a.class))
                   })
}

> coerce2(5, data.frame())
  x
1 5
```

...but I hope that R already supports something more robust and powerful than this.

---

<sup>1 My *assumption* is that I could then address the use-case I'm actually interested in with an expression of the form `coerce(expr1, class(expr2))`.  I think this is a reasonable assumption, but in case it turns out not to hold, I thought I'd spell all this out.</sup>

Comment: See the help file for `as`

Comment: Agreed that `as` will be sufficient in most situations. It will however fail on `as(5, "data.frame")` and the like. Incorporating functions like `getS3method` may help to some extent, as [shown here](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/551c15bb45910df74a5d743d77168235), but even that is not a bullet-proof solution by any means. It would help if we knew a little more about your intended use case.